# Substring extraction issues with regex in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm attempting to do some substring extraction in Ruby through the use of regular expressions, and running into some issues with the regexp being "overly selective".

Here's the target string I'm attempting to match:

`"Exam­ple strin­g with 3 numbe­rs, 2 comma­s, and 6,388­ other­ value­s that are not inclu­ded."`

What I'm attempting to extract is the numerical values in the statement provided. In order to account for the comma, I came up with the expression `/(\d{1,3}(,\d{1,3})*)/`.

Testing the following in IRB, this is the code and result:

```
string = "Exam­ple strin­g with 3 numbe­rs, 2 comma­s, and 6,388­ other­ value­s that are not inclu­ded."
puts strin­g.scan(/(\­d{1,3}(,\d­{1,3})*)/)­
=> "[[\"3\", nil], [\"2\", nil], [\"6,388\", \",388\"]]"
```

What I'm looking for is something along the lines of `["3", "2", "6,388"]`. Here's the issues I need help correcting:

- Why does Ruby include `nil` for each match group that is not comma-delimited, and how do I adjust the regular expression/match strategy to remove that and get a "flat" array?
- How do I prevent the regular expression from matching a sub-expression of the substring I'm attempting to match (that is, `",388"` in `"6,388"`)?
- I did attempt to use `.match()`, but ran into the issue that it simply returned `"3"` (presumably, the first value matched) with no other information apparent. Attempting to index that with `[1]` or `[2]` resulted in `nil`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's a capturing group in pattern, [`String#scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-scan) returns array of arrays to express all groups.

> For each match, a result is generated and either added to the result
>   array or passed to the block. If the pattern contains no groups, each
>   individual result consists of the matched string, `$&`. **If the pattern
>   contains groups, each individual result is itself an array containing
>   one entry per group**.

By removing capturing group or by replacing `(...)` with non-capturing group `(?:...)`, you will get a different result:

```
string = "Example string with 3 numbers, 2 commas, and 6,388 other values ..."
string.scan(/\d{1,3}(?:,\d{1,3})*/)   # no capturing group
# => ["3", "2", "6,388"]
```